Are there circumstances when flagging a non-rude/non-spam but hopeless question on Staging Ground is warranted?
I came across this question on Staging Ground, and I saw that a reviewer had diligently and politely made 3 relevant comments asking for improvements. And this actually troubled me, because the question is pure garbage that nobody should waste their time on. There's no honestly accurate close reason in Staging Ground for this question, so it's just going to linger on Staging Ground for a while, make its way to the main site, be downvoted, closed and deleted. I flagged the question with a custom mod flag to ask for its deletion and it was denied, which wasn't surprising or even necessarily wrong.
The entirety of the question is:

Checksum? Meaning bit 2
What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2 ?
What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2 What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2 What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2 What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2 What’s it mean when a valid checksum is What’s it mean when a valid checksum is 2

This is the only question I've encountered on Staging Ground so far that I thought should be shortcutted to oblivion by a moderator, so I don't think I'm making much additional work for moderators. Is there a place for skipping the normal curation flow, or I'm I just being impatient and perhaps a little jaded in assuming the question will not be improved?

That is what 'very low quality' flags for questions were originally meant for, but unfortunately those are not available for SG posts.

@CPlus there's only a VLQ flag - not a VLQ close reason. The flag sends a post into the review queues while SG's aim is to complete the review there and then. Standard SG reviewer actions should be enough for OP to get the hint.

@bad_coder Some moderators say VLQ is for questions that are not spam or rude but otherwise so nonsensical that they should be immediately deleted by a moderator. Some say that they should not be used for questions at all, but I agree more with the former.

Some mods in the past (Cody, IIRC) argued such content is abusive of the system and therefore qualifies as R/A, as there's no way they didn't do this as a direct response to being told by the system to add more detail and then proceeding to ignore that guidance and posting this... junk... instead. YMMV when flagging as such.

I have seen few questions in Staging Ground where people repeated some sentence or put some other nonsense in order to pass the quality checked which prevented them from posting question. I even spent battling the checker for half an hour trying to put one such question in order which was decent enough, and there was not much other information that could be edited in. So in general flagging such posts as R/A or any other flag is probably counterproductive. Leaving constructive comment and requiring "Major changes" should be enough.

Let's say "no" for now and see if it becomes a problem
Your description of the Staging Ground is not really accurate; in fact, it is well-equipped to handle this sort of question.  That one reviewer was able to put it into the "Major changes" state, which blocks it from being automatically graduated as you describe.  On the main site, this would require three close voters to handle, rather than one.
In theory, the user could come back, actually describe what they're asking, and resubmit it for review.  Is that likely based on the initial post?  Probably not, but most likely, the post won't receive any edits and won't be posted on the main site.  There's no need for additional time to be spent on it by moderators or curators.

Potential issues where moderator intervention may be warranted (none of which apply here):

I'm not sure how Staging Ground questions factor into the automatic question ban.  If it fails to stop people from submitting questions of this quality repeatedly, that could be a problem.
If people repeatedly resubmit questions of this quality for review without any attempt at addressing the issues, that might warrant a moderator message.

As a side note, make sure your flags are clear on what you think should be done.  Your flag said "Nobody should be wasting their time on this quality of question.", which is... not exactly clear on what you want a moderator to do about that.

Hold on; since when does the "Major changes" state prevent others from graduating a question? I could have sworn I've seen questions I marked thus, get graduated promptly thereafter with no meaningful change. But aside from that, my understanding is that questions auto-graduate after a specific amount of time in the queue without other explicit handling... ?

@KarlKnechtel You might be thinking of "Minor edits"? From the help center: "If your question needs minor edits, you can post it immediately after you have edited it. If it needs major changes, you can submit it for evaluation again so reviewers can have another look at your question and evaluate it again." The auto-graduation is if the post does not receive feedback, which doesn't apply if it's received feedback that it needs major changes. (disclaimer to all of this: as a mod, the effects of reviews may differ somewhat from non-mods)

Sounds good. I also thought questions auto-graduated after a certain amount of time.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk unreviewed staging ground posts auto-graduate. The intent being to prevent review task starvation where an asker spends eternity waiting for a reviewer that never comes. ("Unreviewed" isn't quite accurate as there are some non-blocking reviews which include: "minor edits", the first close vote review, and pending flags. All of these do not prevent auto graduation)

I'll have to pay closer attention, then.

"If people repeatedly resubmit questions of this quality for review without any attempt at addressing the issues, that might warrant a moderator message." - We have the "Decline Re-Evaluation option for that. After Re-Evaluation is declined 3 times, the OP is blocked from requesting Re-Evaluation for some time. I don't think a flag is useful in that case unless actual abuse (like a pattern spanning over multiple questions) is visible.

However, I so see another case where custom flags are warrented: Suspicious reviewer behavior. Non-mods with SG access can find suspicious patterns like reviewers just approving all posts they come across and if a reviewer is actually approving a significant qmount of low quality posts or closing a lot of questions that should be marked as "Major Changes", that fully justifies a custom flag IMO. (or if a question gets marked as spam / R/A when it shouldn't as it is the case with the question of concern now).

@dan1st I think the last comment should be a separated question with SG policy later being distilled into a CW for reference.

I don't think this is necessary to be honest.
